# Formal Definition of closed subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})$ be scheme let Z be a closed subset of X ,i have read many definitions of closed subscheme in many books like in Hartshorne , Liu,Qing ,, Ulrich Görtz but i could 't understand the definition because In Hartshorne version he defined closed subscheme as equivalnce classes of closed immersion and he did't talk about what $\mathcal{O}_{Z }$, in the version of Ulrich Görtz  the definition involve the sheaf of ideals $\mathcal{J}$ but he did't mention the equaivalance classes part

1)I am looking for a  definition of the closed subscheme espically
if Z is closed subset of X  and $U$ is a subset of Z what is $\mathcal{O}_{Z}(U)$?

**Edit** i have read this construction of the structure sheaf on Z and
i have two question ,

Let Z is a closed subset of X  with the inclusion $i$ : $Z \rightarrow X $,then
$i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Z} $ is ismorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{X}/ \mathcal{J} $where $\mathcal{J}$ is some sheaf of ideals ,

2)is $ \mathcal{J} $ the kernel of the hmomorphism of modules
$\mathcal{O}_{X} \rightarrow i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Z}$ ?

Then the subscheme is given by $(Z,\mathcal{O}_{Z})= (supp(\mathcal{O}_{Z}/\mathcal{J},\mathcal{O}_{Z}/\mathcal{J})$

3)Why is $Z=supp(\mathcal{O}_{Z}/\mathcal{J})$?

Comment: I think part of your confusion is that a closed subset does NOT have a unique structure sheaf which makes $(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)$ a closed subscheme of $X$. What you might be looking for in some sense is the ‘smallest’ structure sheaf—this is the so-called reduced subscheme structure. See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01J3.

Comment: When do we say that two structure sheaf are the same ,is that the the equavalance which Harsthorne mention is his definition

Comment: @Alex Youcis in you link ,does $\mathcal{O}_{Z}=\mathcal{I}$,but in the link $\mathcal{I}$ is a sheaf of ideal not a sheaf of ring ?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_Z=\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}$ (technically you take this sheaf on $X$ and take its inverse image sheaf in $Z$).

Comment: @Alex Youcis But this hold only in the example in the link what about the general case what are the structure sheaf which we can define on Z?

Comment: I recommend reading the section about closed subschemes in Vakil's book (and also everything else in that book). It helped me immensely to understand closed subschemes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first two questions is yes, For the last question I think it is important to understand the affine case first, the general case is just using sheaf language to glue these affine cases.

In the affine case when you have an ideal $J$ you can naturally define a close subset $V(J)=\{P|J\subset P\}$ which as a topological space is equal to $Spec A/J$ It is also equal to the support of the A-module $A/J$ which by definition is the set of prime ideals $P$ such that $(A/J)_P\not =0$ if you write definition you see that this is equivalent to the condition $J\subset P$.

So it is natural to call the map $Spec\, A/J\to Spec\, A$ a closed immersion and it has all good properties you want, then using the sheaf language you can state the general case just replace $A$ by $O_X$ and ideal $J$ by a sheaf of ideals, and if you want to prove something you can reduce to the case of affines, for example, to compute the support you can choose an affine cover and compute the support locally.

Comment: ,can you specify what are the 1-st and 2-nd question which you have mentined in your answer according to the new edit

Comment: ,what is the structure sheaf of $A/J$?

Comment: I mean the number two question

Comment: did you see the definition of an affine sheme? on a basis it send $D(f)$ to $(A/J)_f$. this is also the answer to question number 1, locally $X$ is affine and 
 the opens $D(f)$ are a basis, for a general $U$ you just cover it by $D(f)$ and define the value as the one dictated by sheaf property

Comment: In fact I suggest that first understand how rings and modules are equivalent to the affine schemes and quasi- coherent sheaves over them, then closed immersion would be an interesting special case.